# How to add a photo in resume/CV?

Tags: moderncv, cv

I want to add a photo on the top right-hand corner of my resume. I have made my resume on the online LaTeX editor overleaf. Here is the link to my code-

https://www.overleaf.com/read/dctgfcsxjkfq

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Also copy-paste the basic version (called, minimal working example) of your code.

Comment: As @xxx--- stated, please do not only post a link, but actual code in your question. Links might get broken over time.

Comment: Please see my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464057/16550. Duplicate question?